# Passing global variable from controller to coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

In my controller I have a global variable, `@var` that is set to an integer, let's say it's equal to 99.

```
@var = 99
```

I am using javascript, (http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/docs/welcome/) in particular, to pass that variable's value into a JS function. I know I can easily just call it in the view like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function() {
    odometer.innerHTML = <%= @var %>;
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

This is bad programming and I'd rather do it the correct way and use coffeescript. How can I access this variable in a CoffeeScript file??

```
setTimeout (->
  odometer.innerHTML = var_variable_here
  return
), 1000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you this gem: [Gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon). Basically, in your controller:

```
@your_int = 123
@your_array = [1,2]
@your_hash = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2}
gon.your_int = @your_int
gon.your_other_int = 345 + gon.your_int
gon.your_array = @your_array
gon.your_array << gon.your_int
gon.your_hash = @your_hash
```

The you can access those variables from your `JavaScript` file:

```
alert(gon.your_int)
alert(gon.your_other_int)
alert(gon.your_array)
alert(gon.your_hash)
```

There is an interesting `Railscast` with a detailed example: [Passing Data to JavaScript](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following:

```
setTimeout (->
  odometer.innerHTML = #{ruby_code_here}
  return
), 1000
```

But **a colleague noticed something on Windows Servers** about CoffeeScript and the usage of ruby code inside it:

```
sayHello (-> alert("#{ 'Hello' }") )
```

Windows Servers will recompile the CoffeeScript into JavaScript every time you render this part, in order to always generate javascript with the proper content of the ruby variable. It makes sense, but on Windows machines, it can lead to performance issues.

A simple workaround is to use simple javascript to set extrapolated variables:

```
:javascript
  var mystring = #{ "hello" }

:coffeescript
  console.log(mystring)
```

There is not performance issue on Unix systems, thanks to ExecJS or TheRubyRacer!